# How to select database and use JOIN with MySQL PHP database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to run this function but can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong (output says my fetch array arg is invalid)?

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'over_app', 'password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pics.Pic Pic LEFT JOIN SeenPics.Seen Seen ON Pic.PicID = Seen.PicID");
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "Your Pic ID: $row['PicID']"; }
```

**Note** The `Pic` table is in the `Pics` database and the `Seen` table is in the `SeenPics` database

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: use `mysql_error` to check the error.

Comment: @Truth have you got that comment in a clipboard somewhere ... could do with that whole comment saved - the amount of times its been written on here

Comment: @ManseUK: `Please, don't use \`mysql_*\` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).` I use [this](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/9137) script

Comment: @Truth I'll change it to MySQLi, thanks

Comment: @truth WOW never heard of stackapps (must be asleep) ... amazing .. thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns a boolean `false` is the query fails .. do this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pic LEFT JOIN Seen ON Pic.PicID = Seen.PicID");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Your Pic ID: $row['PicID']"; 
}
```

### Don't use `mysql_*` [See this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427953/how-to-select-database-and-use-join-with-mysql-php-database/11427982#comment-15075223)

### Update

Now that we have the full facts - ie your attempting a join across multiple databases ... the problem is that your query isnt complete ... try this :

```
SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pics.Pic Pic LEFT JOIN SeenPics.Seen Seen ON Pic.PicID = Seen.PicID
```

Comment: hi I'm wondering if mysql_select_db("Pics", $link); is causing the problem, as I need to access 2 different db's, but this forces only 1?

Comment: That produces this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: the exact code you posted, but with mysql_select_db("Pics", $link); and mysql_select_db("SeenPics", $link); above it.

Comment: forget about the `select_db` command - just do this `SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pics.Pic Pic LEFT JOIN SeenPics.Seen Seen ON Pic.PicID = Seen.PicID` <- this selects the table from the correct database

Comment: Okay this is my exact code (other than the mysql_connect), and I still get the same error:   $result = mysql_query("SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pics.Pic Pic LEFT JOIN SeenPics.Seen Seen ON Pic.PicID = Seen.PicID");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Your Pic ID: $row['PicID']"; 
}

Comment: @sebi the unexpected whitespace error ? if so then it sounds like a problem with quoting or brackets within your script - update your question with **all** of your code and I can have a look

Comment: Maybe is could be something with the database?       <?php


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'over_app', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}



$result = mysql_query("SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pics.Pic Pic LEFT JOIN SeenPics.Seen Seen ON Pic.PicID = Seen.PicID");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Your Pic ID: $row['PicID']"; 
}



?>

Comment: @sebi please put this in your question - its impossible to read in a comment and please include the actual error message you receive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13722/discussion-between-sebi-and-manseuk)